# Is it possible to pivot a SQL Server table with multiple data colums

Tags: c#, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I have a table like this to be exported to Excel

```
name      date          value1  value2  value 3
A       09/09/2015        5       10       2
B       09/09/2015        6       6        22
C       09/09/2015        4       3       11
A       10/09/2015        15      1       2
B       10/09/2015        6       16       27
C       10/09/2015        4       31       11
A       11/09/2015        15      1       2
B       11/09/2015        6       16       27
C       11/09/2015        4       31       11
```

can we pivot this to something like this (using SQL or C# datatable)

```
             09/09/2015        |        10/09/2015       |      11/09/2015
       value1   value2  value3 |  value1  value2 value3  |  value1 value2 value3
A       5         10      12   |    15      1       2    |     15      1     2
B       6          6      22   |    6       16     27    |     6       16    27
C       4          3      11   |    4       31     11    |     4      31   11
```

Comment: please read this article I wrote: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/796651/Client-Side-Multi-Column-Dynamic-Pivot

Answer (score 0):

since your exporting this to Excel why not sumarize the table in Excel into a Pivottable and from there put the name column into the row box, date column into column box, the values into the value box. 
After that you can insert some nice diagrams and then you have a nicer view of the data if you ask me.